# How to use createUser in Facebook Ads (to replace deprecated addUsers)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

Now that I've upgraded to `"facebook/php-ads-sdk": "2.8.*"` (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk), this function of mine doesn't work anymore:

```
public function addToCustomAudience($entriesArray, $audienceId, $inputType = CustomAudienceTypes::EMAIL) {
    $audience = new CustomAudience($audienceId);
    $result = $audience->addUsers($entriesArray, $inputType);
    return $result;
}
```

Apparently `addUsers` is no longer available.

I see a `createUser` function, but it looks quite different, and there is no documentation online about how to migrate from `addUsers` to `createUser`.

What I want to do is simple.

**Given an array of email addresses and an ID of an audience, how can I add all of those email addresses to that Facebook Custom Audience?**

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in the code, `addUsers` is still there, and it's documented on the Developer site.

I just used the latest SDK along with the following code to update an audience:

```
use FacebookAds\Object\CustomAudience;
use FacebookAds\Object\Values\CustomAudienceTypes;

$emails = array(
  'test1@example.com',
  'test2@example.com',
  'test3@example.com',
);

$audience = new CustomAudience(<CUSTOM_AUDIENCE_ID>);

$audience->addUsers($emails, CustomAudienceTypes::EMAIL);
```

Comment: You can see addUsers existed back on Oct 5, 2016 but was marked as "deprecated"  
(https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk/blob/ad5da8006abc9c3498b60b059b4e11285ca5eff1/src/FacebookAds/Object/CustomAudience.php#L352)
and in more recent commits (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk/blob/d51193b19d730ae9274d45540986e1ac311b074d/src/FacebookAds/Object/CustomAudience.php#L363) it is gone.

Comment: ah this is strange, let me find out the new way to do this.

Comment: Looks like we introduced a bug here and we are fixing this, hopefully we can push the fix today.

Comment: Cool, I see that `addUsers` is back in the SDK again: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk/blob/7910756f8100bdd5e90bcef60283979cb802f877/src/FacebookAds/Object/CustomAudience.php#L355

Comment: At https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk/releases, I see that https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk/tree/613d89fbe0424d017a5156658b4e324fbfb5be68 is the latest release (2.9.1), but its diff with 'master' shows that `addUsers` hasn't been readded yet (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk/compare/613d89fbe0424d017a5156658b4e324fbfb5be68...master). And now I'm getting `Failed to update the custom audience: This audience was created from data source FILE_IMPORTED.MULTI_HASHES, which does not support data source FILE_IMPORTED.HASHES_OR_USER_IDS` Really frustrating.

Comment: I see that if I upgrade from 2.8.2 to 2.9.2, I will be able to use `addUsers` again. Here is the diff of the SDK: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk/compare/d51193b19d730ae9274d45540986e1ac311b074d...d7fefc0b3da320d0d6255eaadc937a2bc30bb30b

Comment: Hi @PaulBain, I was hoping you could look at this question about LTV Custom Audiences. Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45438479/facebook-ads-api-to-update-customer-list-value-based

Comment: @Ryan were you able to resolve the `This audience was created from data source FILE_IMPORTED.MULTI_HASHES, which does not support data source FILE_IMPORTED.HASHES_OR_USER_IDS` issue? Getting the same on Python SDK, reported it here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk/issues/433

Comment: @MikhailDubov In my experience, FB doesn't care at all about developers or business owners. They leave their issues and even pull requests abandoned. They introduce breaking changes to their API with almost no warning. Unfortunately I don't have any suggestions for you. Hopefully their Python team cares more. Best of luck.

Comment: @Ryan Ah it's sad to hear that! At least I think I figured out what was wrong in my case - looks like this issue appears only when the custom audience has been created manually in the Ads dashboard but goes away if you create one using the API. I wish this was articulated clearer in their docs...

Answer (score 0):

**This seems to work for my purposes.**

I copied some code from the facebook-php-ads-sdk as a workaround.

```
$audience = new CustomAudience($audienceId);
$params = $this->formatParams($entriesArray, $inputType, [], false);
$audience->createUser([], $params, false); 


/**
 * Copied this from Facebook's https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk/blob/d51193b19d730ae9274d45540986e1ac311b074d/src/FacebookAds/Object/CustomAudience.php#L363
 * Take users and format them correctly for the request
 *
 * @param array $users
 * @param string $type
 * @param array $app_ids
 * @param bool $is_hashed
 * @return array
 */
protected function formatParams(array $users, $type, array $app_ids = array(), $is_hashed = false) {
    if ($type == CustomAudienceTypes::EMAIL || $type == CustomAudienceTypes::PHONE) {
        $normalizer = new EmailNormalizer();
        $hash_normalizer = new HashNormalizer();
        foreach ($users as &$user) {
            if ($type == CustomAudienceTypes::EMAIL) {
                $user = $normalizer->normalize(CustomAudienceTypes::EMAIL, $user);
            }
            if (!$is_hashed) {
                $user = $hash_normalizer->normalize(
                        CustomAudienceTypes::EMAIL, $user);
            }
        }
    }
    $payload = array(
        'schema' => $type,
        'data' => $users,
    );
    if ($type === CustomAudienceTypes::ID) {
        if (empty($app_ids)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
            "Custom audiences with type " . CustomAudienceTypes::ID . " require"
            . "at least one app_id");
        }
        $payload['app_ids'] = $app_ids;
    }
    return array('payload' => $payload);
}
```