# Facebook Ads API to update "Customer List: Value-based"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I created a Custom Audience of type "Customer List: Value-based".

I then used that to create a "value-based Lookalike Audience".

The [documentation for "value-based Lookalike Audience" is here](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/185705781836755).

But what I want to know is:

**How can I use the PHP SDK to update my Custom Audience of type "Customer List: Value-based" via the API?**

(Then, the changes will flow through to the lookalike audience, which is what I use in my ads targeting.)

I cannot find documentation.

P.S. Ding Zhang of Facebook encouraged me to ask the question here since none of the people I reached at FB were willing to answer my question directly. Any awesome FB developers out there? You get major points for being able to answer this one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found some [documentation here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/value-based-lookalike-audience-targeting/v2.9).

```
use FacebookAds\Object\CustomAudienceMultiKey;
use FacebookAds\Object\CustomAudienceNormalizers\HashNormalizer;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\CustomAudienceMultikeySchemaFields;

$users = array(
  array('test1@example.com', 44.5),
  array('test2@example.com', 140),
  array('test3@example.com', 0),
  array('test4@example.com', 0.9),
);

foreach ($users as &$user) {
  $user[0] = hash(HashNormalizer::HASH_TYPE_SHA256, $user[0]);
}

$schema = array(
  CustomAudienceMultikeySchemaFields::EMAIL,
  'LOOKALIKE_VALUE',
);

$audience = new CustomAudienceMultiKey('<CUSTOM_AUDIENCE_ID>');
$audience->addUsers($users, $schema, true);
```

I'm excited to try this out.

P.S. I still can't find the "[magic string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_string)" of `'LOOKALIKE_VALUE'` referenced or defined *anywhere* in the SDK.

[This blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2017/06/12/introducing-value-based-lookalike-audiences/) was how I first found this documentation after *hours* of Google searches.

Answer (score 0):

> P.S. I still can't find the "magic string" of 'LOOKALIKE_VALUE' referenced or defined anywhere in the SDK.

```
FacebookAds\Object\Fields\CustomAudienceMultikeySchemaFields::LOOKALIKE_VALUE
```

In "facebook/php-business-sdk": "^6.0.0"